# How can I use GetType to access methods/properties of derived classes in C#?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract

I have two derived classes, Dog and Bird, which derive from a base class Animal.

Dog has a property Kennel, while Bird has a property Nest.

I want a method (in a separate static class) which can receive an instance of the Animal class, check for the type, and then call other methods which have the Kennel or Nest passed to them as parameters, something like:

```
if (MyAnimal.GetType = Dog)
{MyKennelMethod(MyAnimal.Kennel)}
else if (MyAnimal.GetType = Bird)
{MyNestMethod(MyAnimal.Nest)}
```

I'm guessing this won't work. Is there an way to access the properties of a derived class when you only have the base class? If possible I'd rather not clutter the Dog and Bird classes with individual abstract methods since I would prefer a separate static class to handle all of the methods. I'd also like it to be easily scaleable so I can have hundreds of different new 'animals' deriving from Animal.

Sorry about any mistakes on the code syntax, I don't have an editor at hand at the moment.

Comment: Flow control based on types in a type hierarchy is generally a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: Have you considered using a visitor pattern?

Comment: BTW, the language is called "C#", not "C Sharp".

Comment: @John: Wait, it's not called C-Pound!?

Comment: @John @Brian: I thought it was C-HashMark!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, no problem.

```
Dog dog = myAnimal as Dog;
Bird bird = myAnimal as Bird;
if (dog != null)
   KennelMethod(dog.Kennel);
else if (bird != null)
   NestMethod(bird.Nest);
```

However, I would recommend avoiding this situation in the first place. If you have a method that takes an Animal but really expects a Dog or a Bird, then it sounds like you really want *two methods*, one that takes a Dog and one that takes a Bird.

> If possible I'd rather not clutter the Dog and Bird classes with individual abstract methods. I'd also like it to be easily scaleable so I can have hundreds of different new 'animals' deriving from Animal.

Your requirements are somewhat contradictory; you don't want to encode information about the type hierarchy *in the type code itself*, therefore that stuff has to be outside the type hierarchy, and therefore you have a scalability problem.

Have you considered using a visitor pattern?  That's a fairly standard way of doing virtual dispatch on the runtime type of an object but with the code that is actually executed existing outside of the class.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help. I'll go with this for now and check out the visitor pattern..

Answer (score 3):

You always can cast the animal object. But I don't recommend implementing it in this way, read below.

```
public static void DoSomething(Animal animal)
{
    if (animal is Dog)
    {
      MyKennelMethod((animal as Dog).Kennel);
    }
    else if (animal is Bird)
    {
      MyNestMethod((animal as Bird).Nest);
    }
}
```

This approach breaks the purpose of the inheritance. The right way is exposing a common property in the parent object (animal). This is a very simple example. You could define a common type for Home, and each child object expose it in different ways:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract string Home;
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
   public override string Home = "Kennel";
}

public class Bird : Animal
{
   public override string Home = "Nest";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast:

```
void SomeMethod(Animal animal)
{
    var dog = animal as Dog;
    var bird = animal as Bird;

    if (dog != null)
    {
        // it's a dog - do whatever you want with the dog
    }

    if (bird != null)
    {
        // it's a bird - do whatever you want with the bird
    }
}
```

However, this is a code smell. There is likely a nicer way to design your classes so this kind of casting is unnecessary. For example, `Animal` might expose a `Home` property which returns a `Kennel` when it's a `Dog` and a `Nest` when it's a `Bird`. Or maybe your static method should just take a `Dog` and then have an overload that takes a `Bird`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that Kennel, Nest and methods which have them as params have something in common, right? If so, i suggest interface:

```
interface SweetHome
{ 
    // members
}

class Dog: Animal
{
    public SweetHome Kennel { get; set; }
}

class Bird: Animal
{
    public SweetHome Nest { get; set; }
}
```

This can satisfy your needs. But i still think that methods should be located in classes deriving from Animal, not in some static class outside.